# Why are my Golden Empire Bidens dying?

Tags: plant-health, flowering, repotting, annuals

3 weeks ago I began my first attempt at keeping plants on my balcony. I chose Lavender, Fuchsia, Margot Robert's and Golden Empire Bidens. All seem to be do well enough with the exception of the GEB.

These are the details:

- The plant was flowering abundantly when I purchased it
- I removed it from the thin plastic container it was in
- I loosened the compacted soil around the roots
- I placed it down in a new planter I had partially filled with 'professional potting mix'
- I added the same potting mix around the roots until it was built up to just above the original soil level of the plant
- I compressed the soil around the plant slightly
- I added a small amount more of potting mixture to compensate for the compressed soil
- I watered the plant until water began to drain from the bottom of the planter
- I have watered the plant every second day since then using about a 150mls of water each time
- Originally I had the plant placed on the balcony wall, facing east, getting  morning sun up until about 11am
- A week ago I moved the plant onto the floor where it no longer receives any direct sunlight
- Moving the plant out of the sun was done because I assumed it was getting too much sun, as it was wilting
- After moving it, the plant has deteriorated even faster
- Before moving it, and ever since day one the plant has gradually deteriorated, losing its flowers first and now also the leaves are wilting

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image][image]

Comment: What part of the world are you in? (need to know your current outdoor temperatures). Can you also clarify 'Margot Roberts' - what is the plant name? I'm assuming its the plant with lilac flowers, but I don't recognise it...

Answer (score 2):

Bidens is an annual plant - it is designed to germinate, grow vegetatively and then flower, seed and die. If you happen to catch an annual as it is declining after flowering and it gets set in its ways then that is that. Sometimes you can give it a really good haircut, removing all the dead flowers and the new ones remaining, give it a shot of fertilizer and it will respond by producing even more flowers, going through a second, somewhat diminished, career. It's worth a try, you have little to lose.

An ideal time to buy an annual is when it has a few open flowers (to reassure you that this is the flower you want) plus lots of buds about to open. You take it home and it then produces the masses of flowers for your benefit rather than becoming beautiful in the store. Timing is everything.